# How to convert a sql to lambda entity frameword

Tags: c#, lambda, entity

I'm having a lot of dificulties converting the sql below to lambda. Can someone help me?

```sql
SELECT public."Extract"."Id", public."Extract"."Name", public."ExtractSql"."Sql", public."ExtractSql"."Version"
FROM public."Extract"
join public."ErpExtract" on (public."ErpExtract"."ErpId" = '5221be90-3d97-46fa-9562-4ff9d910c14d' and public."ErpExtract"."ExtractId" = public."Extract"."Id")
join public."ExtractSql" on (public."ExtractSql"."ErpExtractId" = public."ErpExtract"."Id")
join public."ExtractMerchant" on (public."ExtractMerchant"."MerchantId" = '5fb34a5d-e7ee-49a8-a8e3-3df9e9027c39' and public."ExtractMerchant"."ExtractSqlId" = public."ExtractSql"."Id")
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a commercial tool called LINQPad that can do that for you. https://www.linqpad.net/

The standard edition is free but I don't know to be hounest if the standard edition covers your needs. I do know that lots of developers are very happy working with this tool.